# Zend remove params from pagination query string

Tags: zend-framework

Is it possible to remove params from pagination query string?
I have an url like

http://somesite/controller/action/var1/value1/var2/value2/page/3

I want to remove the var1/value1 from pagination url. How will i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a new URL with the url() view helper you could do the following: `$this->url(array('var1' => null));` to reset the 'var1' variabele. Setting it to null it will be removed from the current URL.

Comment: No problem! It's always nice to help somebody :)